# Pod install command returns the error in cocoapod1.0.0

Tags: ios, iphone, git, terminal, cocoapods

I updated cococapod to version 1.0.0. I run the command **Pod install** ,but i got the error immediately like

```
You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
Note: as of CocoaPods 1.0, `pod repo update` does not happen on `pod install` by default.
```

My pod file contain data as following

```
use_frameworks!

def myPods

    pod 'SDWebImage'
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Crashlytics'
    pod 'MBProgressHUD'

end

target 'APP_DEV' do
    myPods
end

target ‘APPTests' do
    myPods
end

target 'APPUITests' do
    myPods
end
```

How to solve this issue? Please help me

Comment: Please make sure your Podfile have proper command for particular pod, this happens when i do make mistake in command

Answer (score 0):

Do as it says:

- Check your Pod names and versions are correct.
- Make sure your Podfile has the source included at the top -> `source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'`
- Run `pod repo update`

**Podfile**

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
use_frameworks!

def myPods

    pod 'SDWebImage'
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Crashlytics'
    pod 'MBProgressHUD'

end

target 'APP_DEV' do
    myPods
end

target ‘APPTests' do
    myPods
end

target 'APPUITests' do
    myPods
end
```

Comment: I tried it.But i got message like..Updating spec repo `master`
Performing a deep fetch of the `master` specs repo to improve future performance..it does not respond..

Comment: Thats strange as it worked for us today. Can you add your Podfile to your question, maybe theres a mistake in there.

Comment: I edited my question with podfile please go through it.

Comment: You need the source at the top I believe. I'll update my answer with what your podfile should look like